Creating a new motion model for the MPPI controller
I am currently trying to implement Nav2 on my USV.
My USV has two motors at the back that can rotate slightly, allowing for vector propulsion.
I have successfully integrated Nav2 with the Navfn Planner and the MPPI controller by simplifying my USV's motion model to a differential one.
While I could use an omni-directional motion model, the velocities (vx and vy) are linked in my case.
Therefore, I would like to create a new motion model for the MPPI controller, but I haven't found any tutorials on this topic. I've attempted to dive into the MPPI code, but it's too abstract for me to follow.
Do you have any guidance on how to implement a new motion model, or do you know of any existing examples?
Thank you, and have a great day!
